# Adding Templavoila template to Typo3 blog

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, templavoila

I am pretty new to Typo3, and I am sorry if my question is too easy to answer =)

I'm using **Templavoila** and I installed the **Typo3 Blog** extension *(T3G?)* and I ticked the checkbox *"Install and use the template provided by the extension"* when setting up my first blog. I hardly managed to get a **html only page** with a sidebar and list of posts.

My problem is that I can't find a way to add a template or any `CSS` to that page. I'd like to fit it into the rest of my website with the logo, menu, etc… but after a day of searching and reading, I haven't find a solution to my problem.

- Is the problem that I'm using Templavoila rather than FLUID?
- Is there a way to add a TV template to my blog?
- How can I add `CSS` to that page (I have tried `page.includeCSS.style` without success)?
- Is it possible to fit that blog in the rest of the website?

**I'm using : Typo3 7.6 - Typo3 Blog 7.6 - Templavoila! Plus 7.2**

*PS : Is it just me or is it pretty difficult for new people to make their way into Typo3 ? ^^ I'm probably just missing something obvious but there isn't much documentation or tutorials dedicated to beginners. I hope it get's easier =)*

Comment: did you manage to get some output on your page or are you still with a blank page? There is an old (but I think still quite good) tutorial about Templavoila that explains quite well its basics: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/doc_tut_ftb1/Index.html

Comment: I have the content of the page (title, posts, text, sidebar…) and it's workning, only there's no CSS… I tried assigning a TV template to my blog page but still just HTML. Even when I tried adding a FCE, I get only the text.  Thank you for the tutorial, I came accross it a few times, it is useful indeed =)

Comment: It is strange because the usual page.includeCSS should work... I don't know :S Can you post your typoscript template?

Comment: I would recommend to not use TemplaVoila, because the support ended for the next TYPO3 version. So if you want to upgrade, you have to rebuild it. Use FLUIDTEMPLATE and check the documentation for it.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Default Typoscript when creating a blog page is : plugin.tx_blog.settings.sharing.enabled = 0
page = PAGE
page.10 < styles.content.get

Comment: I think that in this way you are removing everything that Templavoila does :S
shouldn't it be something like
page.10 = USER
page.10.userFunc = tx_templavoila_pi1->main_page

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi I have tried that : `page.10 = USER`
`page.10.userFunc = tx_templavoilaplus_pi1->main_page` as the only thing I have in my setup. I now have my header, sidebar, css, but only the regular text content. The plugin and Templavoilà contents are not displayed.

Comment: @CCR I don't know now what else to think... I'm not using TV since a lot of time... :S the templavoila page module is showing the blog plugin content element, I presume...

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi I have the default Page module and the TV Page module enabled. As I was using mainly the List module, I didn't notice that the contents where only showing in the default module. Adding TV content and plugins using the TV Page module worked !! Thank you so much for your patience. If you could add that as an answer, adding also the bit on the static Typoscript, I will gladly accept it =)

Comment: @CCR I've added an answer, look if it is satisfying for you. I'm happy you solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templavoila (and Templavoila plus) operate its "magic" by its function to show the content; thus you don't need anymore the usual TypoScript:

```
page.10 < styles.content.get
```

Instead, the page content must be replaced with:

```
page.10 = USER 
page.10.userFunc = tx_templavoilaplus_pi1->main_page
```

Be sure to enable the TemplaVoila page module to manage content with TemplaVoila.The reason is that the "bare" TYPO3 uses the `colPos` field to retrieve the content  (e.g. `styles.content.get` means `colPos=0`) while as far as I remember TemplaVoila uses its own logic and the TemplaVoila page module is necessary (also, as far as I can remember,there is an option to map a TemplaVoila content container to the `colPos` but I could possibly be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

**This is only part of the answer** I was looking for, and it was probably obvious (well not for me indeed).

In the options of the blog template (the Typoscript one) I had to uncheck all the checkboxes (Clear constants, clear setup, rootlevel).
I also deleted the `page.10 < styles.content.get`, if I don't I get all the content but again, HTML only.

I'm facing a new problem now. The list of posts is not showing. Only regular element like text elements are being displayed, the Templavoilà FCE aren't… It is worse for the blog posts, nothing at all is being displayed.

*PS : Should I write a new question for this or is it okay to ask it here ?*

Comment: have you included the static typoscript from the blog extension?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Yes, I have `TYPO3 Blog Template (blog_template)`, `TYPO3 Blog (blog)` and `CSS Styled Content (css_styled_content)` in the "Include static (from extensions)" section. I also changed the "StaticTemplate Files from TYPO3 Extensions:" field to "Always include before this template record"

Answer (score 0):

as maintainer of the TemplaVoilà! Plus extension I'd like to help you. Till yet, I didn't tested the blog extension, but I'm willing to help you there.

Couls you please fill an issue report on https://github.com/pluspol-interactive/templavoilaplus/issues and add there a link to this discussion?

Thanks

PS: I know, this isn't a answer to the question, but not enough reputation to add a comment.

Comment: Hello @Alexander and thank you for helping =) This question got an answer and as it wasn't really a bug, but more like a misuse of the plugin, I'm not sure filling in a issue report is the right thing to do.